# Laravel3: Do I need sanitization if I use Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

This approach;

```
Route::get('admin/user/delete/(:any)', array('as' => 'username', 'uses' => 'admin@user_delete_process'));

public function action_user_delete_process($username)
{
    $result = User::find($username)->delete();
}
```

Do I need to worry about injections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, ORM's handle all of the escaping. Unless you're passing in raw SQL queries, you should be fine without escaping your inputs. To confirm, I dug through Laravel's code, and came across the `execute()` method, which indeed utilizes [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

```
/** laravel/database/connection.php, lines 219-278 */
protected function execute($sql, $bindings = array())
{
    /* ... */
    try
    {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $start = microtime(true);

        $result = $statement->execute($bindings);
    }
    // If an exception occurs, we'll pass it into our custom exception
    // and set the message to include the SQL and query bindings so
    // debugging is much easier on the developer.
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
        $exception = new Exception($sql, $bindings, $exception);

        throw $exception;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I never use raw queries. In worst case, I use it with ?'s and bind values to ?'s. Thanks alot for your reply.